# HSV image different from rgb image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, rgb, hsv

The function `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)` converts an RGB image to an HSV image.

When I save this image and open it using an image viewer, why is it visually different from an RGB image?

**RGB**

[image: RGB image]

**HSV**

[image: HSV image]

Comment: The viewer probably ignores the fact that the color space is HSV, and assumes RGB.  It then shows the H channel as red, etc...

Comment: opencv assumes bgr images in imwrite and imshow and will handle any 3 channel mat as if it was BGR

Comment: @Micka If that's the case, won't the individual ranges (g(0 - 255), s(0 - 360)) interfere or cause some error

Comment: in opencv, hue channel is reduced to 0..180 (half hue) to fit in 1 byte. saturation and value are 0..255 each

Comment: @Micka how would it deal when interpreting a saturation value > 255 as g in bgr

Comment: saturation cant be > 255 after converting from 24 bit bgr to 24 bit hsv in opencv

Comment: have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html and http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite

Comment: please be aware that  cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV) will be wrong if you didnt manually convert to RGB, because typically the color space is BGR so you should use  cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

Comment: @Micka I did take care of BGR and RGB. Thanks for clearing my doubt. Should have tried to figure this on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opencv assumes BGR images in imwrite and imshow and will handle any 3 channel mat as if it was BGR. So it handles the HSV matrix as BGR when we save or show an image.
Now, regarding the viewer, our eyes are used to recognizing the pixels as RGB and hence interpret the H channel as Red and S as Green and V as Blue.
Micka explained it beautifully in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I just finally understood it myself!!

So here is the explanation:

Lets say I had an image with every pixel being the same in a BGR format of **[255,0,0]**. Which means this image is completely blue.

[BGR Blue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKV6H.png)

Now, using OpenCV if you convert BGR to HSV (a formula runs in the background to convert each pixel from BGR to HSV), each of the pixel's value changes to **[120,255,255]** representing **Hue = 120, Saturation = 255 and Value = 255.**

[HSV IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jwBl.png)

This image of **[120,255,255]** looks slightly yellow to us on our screens because pixels itself would work in BGR format! So to the pixel it would be **Blue = 120, Green = 255 and Red = 255.**

[BGR version of HSV image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3M8G.png)

So I made a BGR image with each pixel value being **[120,255,255]** and it looks same the HSV image! I have posted the image of the pixel values as well.

[Pixel Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfuQS.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 #opencv

# Make a Black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)


# Make All pixels with Blue value to its highest (make blue image)
img[:,:,0] = 255

# Convert BGR to HSV image
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.imshow("BGR Blue Image", img)
cv2.imshow("HSV version of Blue Image",hsv_img)

print("\n BGR pixel value: ", img[5,5]) # output is [255,0,0]
print("\n HSV pixel value: ", hsv_img[5,5]) # output is [120,255,255]

cv2.waitKey(0)

# Now make the original image to the same pixel value as HSV output
img[:,:,0] = 120
img[:,:,1] = 255
img[:,:,2] = 255

cv2.imshow("BGR version of the HSV pixel value Image", img)

print("\n BGR pixel Value of the HSV image: ", img[5,5])
print("\n")

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```